# How to click on a image icon which is a ImageView type using Selendroid?

Tags: java, android, selenium, selendroid

I need to click on a image icon which is a `ImageView` type. By using inspector I got the following code:

```
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//ImageView)[1]"));
element1.click();
```

But when I am using this code in my script then its showing `"Element not found"`. I also tried by using `ID` of that image icon. The same error occurs.

Comment: Without seeing the page, any answer you get is going to be pure guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

I think `click() call` before the **page load** do like

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("myDynamicElement"));

element1.click();
```